# Using Quartz as a Queue Processor

Tags: quartz.net

I am looking into Quartz.NET to process our daily jobs and it seems to handle our scenarios.  We also have jobs that are added to a queue table in SqlServer and this table is polled for work every few seconds.  How can this be handled using Quartz.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz.net will replace the queue/polling functionality. Quartz.net has its own queue (jobstore) which it polls and executes jobs from it.

What you will do is schedule your jobs in  quartz (queue them) and then Quartz.Net will execute them based on the time they need to be executed (determined by the trigger). In Quartz.Net the job (does the work) is separate from the trigger (determines when I job should run).

Comment: They would need to be run when queued, so I guess I could put in the current datetime to cause it to fire immediately. Also since multiple boxes will be sharing the queue is the sql server store the best way to go?

Comment: Yes on both. If you are running multiple instances you definitely need to use a db based store.

Comment: I am finding that the default jobstore does not behave like a queue. The jobs are not executed strictly in the order that I am putting them in the queue.  All are using a trigger with "StartNow()".

Comment: That's right. Quartz.net doesn't follow the strict first in first out semantics of a Queue (as in the data structure). If you need to be strict about the order then you'd have to use a message queue probably. But those don't support schedules. If you need jobs to happen in strict order in Quartz.Net you'd need to chain them.

Comment: In my opinion this invalidates the answer. Quartz.NET is inherently not a queue, but a scheduler and job chaining is awkward. I would say the correct answer is that Quartz is not well suited for implementing a queue.

Comment: The OP asks about processing daily jobs. That is handled by Quartz.Net. It also supports scheduling ad hoc jobs, that the OP calls queued. It seems the scenario can be covered by both scheduled jobs and ad hoc jobs. It doesn't seem the OP is actually looking to implement a queue.